# Duplicating data across windows to fill in an indefinite number of spots

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to duplicate data records into future windows. The issue this solves is that computing statistics on each window will be more accurate since this data is continuous (like temperature) and requires a baseline value.

In these diagrams, each box represents a fixed window. The numbers in each window represent data coming in a PCollection coming from a source.

This is an example input PCollection:

```
+---------+---------+---------+--------->
| 1  2    |       3 |         |         |
+---------+---------+---------+--------->
```

And the resulting output PCollection:

```
+---------+---------+---------+--------->
| 1  2    | 2     3 | 3       | 3       |
+---------+---------+---------+--------->
```

Notice how the latest data point (based on event timestamp) is forwarded to the next window. If there are multiple empty windows, the value must be re-forwarded.

I have solved the problem of forwarding once by running the windowed PCollection through a stateful DoFn that emits an extra duplicated and modified element:

```java
public class DupeFn extends DoFn<Datum, Datum> {
    @StateId("latest")
    private final StateSpec<ValueState<Datum>> latestStateSpec = StateSpecs.value();

    @TimerId("emit")
    private final TimerSpec emitSpec = TimerSpecs.timer(TimeDomain.EVENT_TIME);

    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(
            @Element Datum element,
            OutputReceiver<Datum> receiver,
            IntervalWindow window,
            @StateId("latest") ValueState<Datum> latest,
            @TimerId("emit") Timer emit
    ) {
        emit.set(window.maxTimestamp());

        Datum prev = latest.read();

        if (prev == null || element.timestamp > prev.timestamp) {
            latest.write(element);
        }

        receiver.output(element);
    }

    @OnTimer("emit")
    public void emitLatest(
            OutputReceiver<Datum> receiver,
            IntervalWindow window,
            @StateId("latest") ValueState<Datum> latest
    ) {
        Datum last = latest.read();

        // modify the timestamp such that it lands in the next window
        last.timestamp = window.end().getMillis() + 10;
        last.id += " DUPED";

        receiver.outputWithTimestamp(last, new Instant(last.timestamp));
    }
}
```

The issue now is that nothing will be duplicated into the proceeding window if there's an empty window. Ideally, the behaviour would be as described in the diagram above.

Is there a way of doing this?

**Edit**
I found [this](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/1aee9a87616b21a0af0911708c9e0a4ad35f82be/website/src/_posts/2019-06-11-looping-timers.md) relevant unpublished blog post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a minor issue with the Beam docs at the moment, once thats fixed the blog should appear. The looping timers will give you part of the solution to this problem. As it will ensure there is activity in every interval window even in the absence of data.

Edit: The blog is now available here [Link to Blog](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2019/06/11/looping-timers.html)

The next piece requires the use of Global Windows which brings with it some more complexity. There will be a talk on this at the Apache Beam Summit next week.

[Berlin Summit](https://beam-summit.firebaseapp.com/schedule/2019-06-20)

In order to keep the state you will need to flow your fixed windows aggregations into a GlobalWindow. However GlobalWindow does not guarantee order, so you will need to follow something along the lines of this flow:

@ProcessElement

- Save elements into a BaggedState
- Create a EventTime timestamp, if no timestamp is set already. 
  [You will need something like this to solve for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55912522/setting-a-timer-to-the-minimum-timestamp-seen/55912542#55912542)

@OnTimer

- Read and sort the BaggedList by Timestamp
- Chain the final value from each aggregation into the next aggregation if the next aggregation does not have a value ( It was made using the looping timer not external data source).
- Output all values where the timestamp is < then the OnTimer.Timestamp
- Clear the baglist of any already processed element, please note today this is inefficient as you can not remove specific elements from the list. If you look on the dev lists on Apache Beam there is a nice discussion on request for Sorted Map in the future which will be very useful here.

Sorry its not a short answer!